# Setting quality with imagemagick?

Tags: php, compression, imagemagick

I use the following code to create a thumbnail on the site:

```
$small_image = new Imagick($large_path."/".$pic['image']);
$small_image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
$small_image->writeImage($small_path."/".$pic['image']);
```

It sets it's own quality and I tried adding

```
$small_image->setCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$small_image->setCompressionQuality(1);
```

But that didn't change a thing.  I also tried

```
$img = new Imagick($small_path."/".$pic['image']);
$img->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
echo $img->setCompressionQuality(1); // should come out ugly
$img->writeImage();
```

But even that didn't change the size with quality 1.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to reduce filesize?

What happens when you call getCompressionQuality?

Comment: Yea to reduce the size.  getCompressionQuality just shows what I set in setCompression.  Without setCompression beign set getCompressionQuality just showns 0

Answer (score 9):

I think you want:

```
$small_image->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$small_image->setImageCompressionQuality(1);
```

Note the "Image" between the "get"/"set" and "Compression".